# How to delete all tables with prefix "bkp" from a given database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, drop-table

I have a SQL server 2005. In that server I have 3 databases -> a,b,c.

If I want to delete tables

1. Tables only from database "c".
2. The table's name should start with "bkp"
3. Table should be created one day before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE C
GO

SELECT
'DROP TABLE ' + name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE create_date >= '20101211'   -- substitute your date you're interested in
AND name like 'bkp%'
```

This will create as output a list of `DROP TABLE:....` statement - copy those and paste them into a new SSMS window and execute those - and you're done!

Comment: My Doubt is...Sys.Tables is common for all databases right. So ...will it delete from databases ?

Comment: @Anish: **no it's not** - `sys.tables` is specific to the database you're in - when you do `USE C` you get only the tables that are in database C.