# Delete all tables with a certain prefix name in a SQL 2008 database programmatically

Tags: sql, tablename

I have 3000+ tables in my SQL 2008 database with names like listed below, that all starts with `tempBinary_`, that I need to delete programmatically, how do I do that? 
I don't know if I prefer the solution in a SQL-script or with use of LINQtoSQL, i guess both are fine.

`tempBinary_002c90322f4e492795a0b8a14e2f7c99`
`tempBinary_0039f7db05a9456f96eb3cd6a788225a`
`tempBinary_0057da9ef0d84017b3d0bbcbfb934fb2`

I've used Like before on columns, but I don't know if it good for table names too.
Maybe something like this, where LIKE is used, can do it? I don't know.

```
Use [dbo].[database_name]
DROP TABLE table_name
WHERE table_name LIKE 'tempBinary_%'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the solution might be close to this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424038/how-to-delete-all-tables-with-prefix-bkp-from-a-given-database

Comment: Cant do this in Linq2SQL, removed tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @stmt varchar(max) = ''
declare @tbl_name varchar(255)


DECLARE tbl_cursor CURSOR  FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR select name 
        from sysobjects 
        where xtype='u' and name like 'tempBinary%'
OPEN tbl_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor
INTO @tbl_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @stmt = @stmt + 'drop table ' + @tbl_name + ';' +  CHAR(13)


    FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor 
    INTO @tbl_name
end
CLOSE tbl_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tbl_cursor;    

execute sp_sqlexec @stmt
```

Comment: if you put a print @stmt before execute sp_sqlexec you'll see the drop statements line by line

Comment: Allright thanks. Hold on I'll test it, and get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: I made a test, is kind slow this script, the only improvement is to declare the cursor  FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY, I'll edit